# Navbar item pushing everything right CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap navbar. Code:

```
<div align="center">
    <!-- Static navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="nav_list" style="margin-top:30px; float:left;"></div>
            <div id="logo">
                <a href=""><img src="" style="height:50px; margin-top:20px;"></a>
            </div>
            <img id="loading" src="images/loading.gif"
                 style="height:50px;margin-top:20px; display:none">
        </div>
    </div>
```

I would like the images to stay bang in the middle of the navbar and the nav_list to float to the left of it. However right now when nav_list is included it floats to the left but all the images are pushed right.

Here is the css:

```css
#nav_list {
    background: url(icon_nav.png) no-repeat left top;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 27px;
    width: 33px;
    float:left;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
}
#nav_list.active {
    background-position: -33px top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding:

```css
#nav_list {
    background: url(icon_nav.png) no-repeat left top;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 27px;
    width: 33px;
    float:left;
    position: absolute; /* <--- */
    text-align: center;
}
```

Has done the job quite nicely. Thanks.